# Identify a story: female character with wings, involved in a romance with a human

Tags: story-identification

I vaguely remember a story I read 20 years ago (but most likely is much older.)

- It took place on a ship on an ocean (on some other planet, I think.)
- There was an alien (I think) female character, with wings, as a crew member, hired for scouting.
- She was involved in a romantic relationship with a male (human) crew member, but physical contact with him was causing her pain (burning the skin, I think.)
- The story was narrated by the human.
- Most likely a short story, in a magazine.

I know it is not much for an identification, but maybe someone could help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Just to clarify, was this a _short_ story? If so, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably Bruce Sterling's first novel [Involution Ocean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_Ocean?msclkid=2600ef9acebe11ec9aaa7d7061ebccda), first published in 1977 which fits in with your timeframe.  At around 175 pages it is not a long story but longer than a short story would be.

The protagonist is an human addict of flare, a drug found within the sand whales that can only be found on the planet Nullaqua.  He signs onboard a whaling vessel to be close to the source of flare after it is made illegal.

The winged female is a "bat-lady", a lookout/scout for the ship, and she and the protagonist do have a relationship, but the touch of his hands cause her skin to bruise and become inflamed iirc.

There are a number of reviews on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23526315-involution-ocean?msclkid=18d09f53cebe11eca4105e70e6d785fd), one of which sums up the points that match your question nicely.

> A nod to Moby Dick, set on a dust sea in a distant planet. It’s got all the necessary ingredients: hardened seamen who do difficult work on a whaling ship with an obsessed captain, told by a dispassionate observer. The dust sea itself, and the world on which it exists, make for a fascinating and well-drawn setting (as long as you can suspend your disbelief in the geological stability of a giant hole in the planet many miles deep). I never really connected with the protagonist, whose poor choices were supposedly dictated by a powerful addiction, but we never saw him experience any withdrawal symptoms. I didn’t buy the romance with the bat-woman, or the strange behaviors exhibited by the rest of the crew. The ending just left me adrift and confused. All told, the sense of wonder provoked by the world wasn’t enough to balance out the rest. Maybe it’s because I never cared for Moby Dick in the first place

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you :)